# Return modified object with Underscore/Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

With underscore, how can I format a particular value and return a new object?

For example I have the following structure:

```
var myData = [
  {
    'created': '2015-05-19T21:45:23',
    'sales': 200,
  },
  {
    'created': '2015-05-20T21:45:33',
    'sales': 100,
  },
  {
    'created': '2015-05-21T21:45:43',
    'sales': 140,
  },
  {
    'created': '2015-05-23T21:45:43',
    'sales': 200,
  }
];
```

I'd like to format the `created` key/value using angular's date filter function. How can I return a new object with the proper formatting?

When I do something using `_.each`, it doesn't work.

```
_.each(myData, function(k) {
  return $filter('date')(k.created, 'short');
})
```

What I want to output is:

```
var myModifiedData = [
  {
    'created': '5/19/15 9:45 PM',
    'sales': 200,
  },
  {
    'created': '5/20/15 9:45 PM',
    'sales': 100,
  },
  {
    'created': '5/21/15 9:45 PM',
    'sales': 140,
  },
  {
    'created': '5/22/15 9:45 PM',
    'sales': 200,
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

each will only iterate over array but if you want to return new array you can use map (new in ES5):

```
$scope.newData = myData.map(function(item) {
    return $filter('date')(item.created, 'short');
});
```